# Get return value of object in class

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a library that returns an exception, part of library code is:

```
class APIException(Exception):                                                                     
    pass
raise APIException((u'APIException[%s] %s' % (response['return']['status'],response['return']['message'])).encode('utf-8'))
```

My code is:

```
except Exception as e:
```

Now I want to get the string part of returned object (APIException class) and decode it.
As the class does not have any get functions, how can I do that?

Comment: You can get all of the arguments from `e.args`. This is covered in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Comment: Correct @jonrsharpe